# Create GUID in TypeScript - function is valid in JS but not TS

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/6743682) to create a GUID-type string in my angular4/TypeScript web app.

Here is the function I'm writing:

```js
function uuidv4() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  )
}
console.log(uuidv4())
```

TypeScript is giving me the following error:

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number[]' and '-1000'.
```

What do I need to change to make this TS compatible?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose the error points to another location in your code. Search for "-1000"

Comment: I second that what @hgoebl has said. The issue is somewhere else. https://plnkr.co/edit/MxwthKjqxCWRAicGtcXV. Please provide andular2 code.

Comment: @hgoebl - when I remove the function the code compiles beautifully, so the problem has to be within the function. As specified, I'm using Angular 4, with TS version 2.2.2 . VS code is running version 2.3.2.

Comment: Also, the following chars are highlighted in my editor (vs code): `[1e7]+-1e3`. Can it be a TS version issue?

Comment: OK, I see. Seems like TS compiler internally converts -1e3 to -1000. If you want to get rid of the problem quickly, just replace the thing before `.replace` with `'10000000-1000-4000-8000-100000000000'`

Comment: @hgoebl - Huh. Can you please explain why TS does this and how this works?

Comment: You can generate unique values by new Date().getTime().toString() + Math.random().toString().split(".")[1]
Just a thought

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to leave the somehow cryptic code (a puzzle?) almost as it's ingenious original but TypeScript compatible, you could use:

```
function uuidv4(): string {
  return (''+[1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, ch => {
      let c = Number(ch);
      return (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
    }
  )
}
```

Unscrambled:

- `[1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11` produces the string `10000000-1000-4000-8000-100000000000` and saves an unbelievable amount of characters ;-)
- TypeScript is not aware that the expression is intended to produce a string. (This could be regarded as bug IMHO.)
- When you start the expression with `'' +`, type inference detects the expression as string and compiler now accepts concatenating the array with the numbers. A more readable form would be `'' + 1e7 + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11`, because then you no longer need the `[]` to treat the `+` operators as string concatenation instead of a numeric addition.
- The next problem arises with the auto-coercion of `c` from string to number. For this, I've added an explicit conversion from `ch` as string to `c` as number.

That's another proof that "just rename your *.js files to *.ts and you have valid TypeScript" is not true in all cases. I'm still convinced that using TypeScript pays off very soon and such small changes do not cost much.